# where are the install instructions for google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, installation

I fear this is going to be a stupid question, but here goes.

I am following the very first steps for getting started with GAE- http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html

step 1: get python 2.5 - check

step 2: download the Google App Engine SDK for Python (linux/other platforms) - check

step 3: Follow the instructions on the download page to install the SDK on your computer.

I cannot see any installation instructions on the download page or anywhere else on the web for that matter. Perhaps I should just reboot to windows and try again (the msi package will install itself somewhere appropriate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html

> If you are using the Zip archive version of the SDK, you will find
>   these commands in the google_appengine directory.

On GNU/Linux you just need to extract the zip archive.

Comment: Thanks. 'where to extract it to?' was the stumbling block for me. I am probably not familiar enough with Linux to use development tools successfully. This page http://www.digimantra.com/google/google-app-engine/install-run-google-app-engine-linux/ suggests dumping it all on my desktop. I'll see how that goes.

Comment: You don't need to extract it in a specific place, that's up to you :)